# How to extract data from dev tools using selenium and java

Tags: java, rest, selenium, testing

I am trying to extract a get call from the dev tools section of my site and can't figure out how to do it.

Im opening the dev tools using

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
```

But I'm trying to extract a certain get call. Basically the call appears in the exact same way each time but the number at the end changes.

Example: http//test.com/ref/restdata?appointmentId=2444

So basically I'm trying to grab the request and extract the number when the page opens.

Any ideas on this?